# Ubuntu server to project

Tags: server, webserver

Hej 
I am making a project to my exam this summer. 
It's about finding the best server solution for a company with
400 employees in two sites one in Aarhus and one in Copenhagen and growing.
The server shall include web server, backup server and file share server. 
All employees should have access to these options but there will only be two server
admins controlling it.
So my problem is that I can't find info about how big your market part is on the market, 
is the price still zero for a company and what is your advantages and disadvantages compared to mac and windows?

Hope you will help me get closer to an answer for my project

Best regards 
Jakob Nørholm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

**The overall market share of Ubuntu Server is about 9.3 percent** and counting, popular sites using Ubuntu include Wikipedia, The Internet Archive, Buzzfeed and others.<sup>[[1]](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/os-ubuntu/all/all)</sup>

**Ubuntu is and always will be free**<sup>[[2]](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu)</sup>, the same goes for the server version.<sup>[[3]](http://www.ubuntu.com/server)</sup>
There are paid-for enterprise support options available<sup>[[4]](http://www.ubuntu.com/server/management)</sup>, but the base product (Ubuntu itself and the bundled software) won't cost you a penny, even if you'd make millions of dollars using it.
There is **free community support** here on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/), as well as the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/) and the [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) to help you with all Ubuntu related questions or problems, completely free of charge.

Further advantages of Ubuntu (and, to be fair, GNU/Linux in general) include **Freedom** (no restrictions, no vendor lock-in...), **Security**<sup>[[5]](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features)</sup> and **cost-efficiency** (no license fees, free upgrades, lower maintenance cost).
Also, the **included package management system** (APT, Advanced Packaging Tool) and the many freely available administration tools make upgrading and deploying software as well as other maintenance tasks across many computers and company networks easy and painless.

#### Further reading

- [Frequently Asked Questions about the Ubuntu Server Edition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq)
- [Server case studies | Ubuntu Insights](https://insights.ubuntu.com/category/case-studies/?topic=server)
- [Ubuntu adoption case studies (for companies, associations, schools)](http://spreadubuntu.org/en/material/poster/ubuntu-adoption-case-studies-companies-associations-schools)

#### References

1. [“Usage statistics and market share of Ubuntu for websites”](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/os-ubuntu/all/all), W3Techs, January 2014
2. [“About Ubuntu”](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu), Ubuntu.com
3. [“Ubuntu Server - for scale-out computing”](http://www.ubuntu.com/server), Ubuntu.com
4. [“Server Management”](http://www.ubuntu.com/server/management), Ubuntu.com
5. [“Security/Features”](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features), Ubuntu Wiki, May 2014

Comment: What about the market share with Ubuntu Server for companies. Without thinking on the websites server but as a fileshare and active directory server ?